# Can anyone explain how we use the linear extension theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having problems using the linear extension theorem.
For example:

Let V be finite-dimensional, and let W ⊂ V be a proper subspace of V . Fix a vector v0 ∈ V such that v0 is not in W. Show that there exists a linear
transformation T : V → R for which T(v0) = 1 and W ⊂ ker T.

Hint: choose a basis for V in a suitable way and use the linear extension theorem.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a basis $v_0,\dotsc,v_m,w_1,\dotsc,w_n$ for $V$ such that $w_1,\dotsc,w_n$ is a basis for $W$. Then define $T:V\to\Bbb R$ by $T(v_k)=1$ and $T(w_k)=0$. The linear extension theorem implies that $T$ is well-defined and one easily checks that $W\subset\ker T$.